# What would happen if I changed my hostname to 'localhost'?

Tags: networking, dns, localhost, hostname

- Would my machine function correctly?
- Would other machines on the network be able to ping mine by name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would my machine function correctly?

Yes.

> Would other machines on the network be able to ping mine by name?

Depends on the specific method other machines currently use to resolve your host name into your IP address.

- plain `localhost` using DNS or NetBIOS:

  - On Windows, `localhost` would always resolve to the loopback address, since "localhost" is hardcoded in the resolver.
  - On Linux, the exact results depend on the contents of `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. However, on 99% of Linux systems, `localhost` always resolves to the loopback address, since nsswitch gives priority to `/etc/hosts`.
- `localhost.local` using mDNS (Avahi, Bonjour):

  - Would keep working and resolve to your PC's address, since it is different from `localhost` and does not get any special treatment.
- `localhost.yourdomain`:

  - Would keep working, since it is different from `localhost` and does not get any special treatment.